Oracle apex session timeout error when loading data from frontend
I have data load button which loads the data into local table then hits API and again save the api staus into bd tables, here when i load more than 20000k records, the plsql block is taking more than 300 seconds so i am getting timeout error when i load the data from apex button, due to the screen is idle for more than 5to 10 mins.
Any suggestions on this, i want to succeed this without timeout error.

Maybe you can use a AJAX callback instead of directly executing the PLSQL code. This way,(I am not sure if it fits your business requirements though) you can run the code asynchronously on the server side whereas the clien-side(browser) is not blocked/timed out.

Please do not spam tag. You're NOT on oracle 11g or oracle 10g, APEX is not supported on them - tagging those version does not help you. The tag "apex-code" is for a product by Salesforce that is not related to Oracle APEX. The "oracle-apex" tag should be just fine

A screen shouldn't be idle more than a couple of seconds or user might lose focus and close it. Instead of loading AND executing API in a single process, it might be more performant/scalable if the process is split in 2 parts.
Step 1: load all rows in a temporary table with no processing. This shouldn't timeout (but of course if the file gets too big everything can time out. Once the loading is completed, inform the user that the rows are loaded and now need to be processed.
Step 2: The processing can be done with a page process but that is probably likely to time out too. Alternatives are an AJAX callback or an automation -
up to you to pick what is easiest.
